# FCFS inside memory list

Tags: job-scheduling

Hi i am new in java programing. I've created a program to allocate 20 block inside 10 memory.
Here's the code

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class BestFit
{
    private int[] job;//f
    private int[] memBlock;//b
    private int[] jobStatus;
    private int[] jobAT;
    static private int[] memTaken;
    static int[] ff;
    private int[] jobCC;
    private int[] ArrivalTime;
    private int[] waitingTime;
    private int[] turnaroundTime;


    public BestFit()
    {
        job = new int[]{5040,4600,1060,1950,6950,6410,2960,3070,2770,7790,5680,9150,7880,3870,7160,8880,4410,6130,6750,2560};
        memBlock = new int[]{4400,6200,9300,1000,4200,8200,4600,3700,6300,2900};
        memTaken = new int[20];
        ff = new int[20];//to store no. of block that used by particular file
        jobCC = new int[]{2,8,10,1,10,8,4,2,6,7,1,1,1,8,8,2,5,7,6,7};//cpu cycle
        ArrivalTime = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20};
        waitingTime = new int[]{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
        turnaroundTime = new int[]{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

    }
    public void BestFitAlgo()
    {
        int[] frag = new int[25];
        int i,j,nb,nf,sizeDifference;
        int lowest = 10000;
        nf = 20;
        nb = 10;
        int startTime = 1;
        int complete = 1;
        int totalTime = 1;
        int waitTime;
        int tTime = 1;
        Arrays.sort(memBlock);
        for (i=0;i<nf;i++)
        {
            if (complete != 20)
            {
                for (j=0;j<nb;j++)
                {
                    sizeDifference = memBlock[j] - job[i];
                    if (sizeDifference>=0)
                    if (lowest>sizeDifference)
                    {
                        ff[i] = j;//no of block = j
                        lowest = sizeDifference;
                        complete++;
                        System.out.println("Job: "+i+" is added to block: "+ff[i]+" and being process");
                        for (int k = 1;k<jobCC[i];k++)
                        {
                            startTime++;
                        }
                        if(startTime == jobCC[i])
                        {
                            waitingTime[i] = tTime - ArrivalTime[i];
                            turnaroundTime[i] = jobCC[i] + waitingTime[i];
                            System.out.println("Job: "+i+" is fully processed.Block: "+ff[i]+" is free");
                            System.out.println("Arrival Time: "+ArrivalTime[i]);
                            System.out.println("Start time: "+totalTime);
                            System.out.println("CPU cycle: "+jobCC[i]);
                            totalTime +=startTime;
                            startTime = 1;
                            tTime = totalTime;
                            System.out.println("Waiting time: "+waitingTime[i]);
                            System.out.println("Turnaround time: "+turnaroundTime[i]+"\n");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            frag[i]=lowest;
            lowest = 10000;
        }
        System.out.println("File No:\tFile_Size:\tBlock_No:\tBlock_Size:\tFragment");
        for (i=0;i<nf&&ff[i]!=0;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(i+"\t\t"+job[i]+"\t\t"+ff[i]+"\t\t"+memBlock[ff[i]]+"\t\t"+frag[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("\nTotal time: "+totalTime);
    }
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        BestFit b = new BestFit();
        b.BestFitAlgo();
    }

}
```

For now the job can be allocated to the memory block by fcfs but the problem now is the next job wont be able to enter the memory list ( where all the block) until the previous job is done. So there are 9 free memory block everytime a job enter.
How do i make it so that job can enter the block simultaneously (with the condition the desired mem block is not occupied and based on arrival time).
I know how fcfs work but that is with only 1 memory block. I've been googling all day trying to find how fcfs work in multiple memory block but no avail. 
I hope anyone can help me to understand how it work and maybe a hint on how to implement in in coding.
Thanks in advance
EDIT: i put my code instead so anyone can get a clear view of my problem.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. still learning how to how to post on this forum properly :) @kebs

Comment: Well, actually, this is **not** a forum... You could ge some benefits from reading [these pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).